# How do you display the contents of a database over many pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, posts

I'm making a rails app that handles many, many posts. What i want to do it display the posts over *x* number of pages with 5 posts per page. I've looked around a lot and have not been able to find a solution. I'm new to ruby on rails and don't yet know enough to be able to separate the posts by page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two gems that could help you: [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) or [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

Comment: I've been using will_paginate for years. Super easy to integrate with helper methods to generate number per page and numbered navigation

Comment: kaminari on the other hand is the new kid on the block and appears to be more actively maintained that will_paginate.  will_paginate also had issues with rails 3 a few months ago though these may have been cleared up now

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the mysql limit clause. There's a good tutorial here that gives specifics on using it for paging. The tutorial is for PHP but you only really need the concept in order to apply it to rails.

http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2008/10/16/mysql-limit-paging/